# Up or down a notch?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, prepositions

*(I apologize for the silly question ahead)*

I've lost some weight recently, and I was able, for the first time today, to close my belt buckle using a notch higher than usual...

For the life of me I can't figure out if I "went up a notch" or "down a notch"?

Is this phrase even applicable for an actual belt?

Comment: I feel like if anything, this usage would be considered a pun.

Comment: In the _Corpus of Contemporary American English_ I find many sentences containing _down a notch_, but none of them has a reference to a belt.

Comment: Aside: there's also the colloquial expression *put a notch in your belt* or similar, referring to a knife-mark made in tally of sexual conquests. A guitarist may notch his guitar for the same reason. It originally arose from the Old-West practice of notching the stock of your gun for every man you killed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*down a notch* means *down a level*.
It is used in sentences like

> Turn the volume down a notch.

or, figuratively, in sentences like

> Anyone who names a board game after himself needs to be taken down a notch or two.
>   Soon he was taken down a notch.

The expression you are looking for is probably *to notch (something) tighter*.

> She notched her belt tighter.

Comment: +1 I love these short but accurate answers

Answer (score 2):

Normally, waistbands are described as being 'taken in' or 'let out'.  I would suggest that when describing notches on a belt (notches ***in*** a belt?) that the proper phrases would be something like, "After dieting for two weeks I'm buckling my belt in one notch in."

Answer (score 0):

“Go *up* (or *down*) a notch” is not the usual idiom. I would avoid it. It is idiomatic to say something like:

- “I *took* my belt *in* a notch” (to indicate a smaller waist or a condition of extreme hunger)
- “I *let* my belt *out* a notch” (to indicate a larger waist or a condition of extreme satiety)

These expressions “take in” and “let out” are also used when referring to alterations of clothing for a similar purpose. For example, one might have one’s trousers “taken in” or “let out”.

See “take in” and “let out” at *MacmillanDictionary.com*.

Answer (score 0):

well simply spoken , you've taken your weight down a notch and you've taken your waist or belt in a notch ( equivalent to up a notch)

up or down a notch comes from being able to increase or decrease things using a notch ( like a groove or hole to adjust things )

people are correct in saying that it's more frequently used in an up or down sense as opposed to a in or out

you'd be expressing yourseld correctly by saying you dropped your weight down a noth or you took your waist or belt up or in a notch

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello, kev. The best parts of your answer have already been given.