# After losing weight, how do I say I can wear my belt tighter?

Tags: word-choice, expressions

So, yes, I have been losing weight, so far down 4kg and 2 to 3 inches in waist.

I am happy and when I was trying to say to someone that now I can wear my belt tighter, I don't know how to say it because I wonder:

- Is there a specific name for the holes on the belt?
- Is there a specific verb for wearing a belt?

In the end, I said "I can now comfortably **buckle** 2 to 3 **holes** tighter when wearing my belt."

Sure, it is easy enough to be understood, but is there a better way of expressing that? Also, can I use "buckle" here for belt, in a same sense that it is used in "buckle up" (car seat-belt)? I know the word buckle actually refers to the rectangular metal thing that holds the belt in place, but the best I could think of is "buckle two holes tighter".

Comment: Related: [Up or down a notch?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10598/up-or-down-a-notch)

Comment: If you're happy about the situation then be careful to imply that when describing your belt; belt-related idioms in English often imply *undesired* weight loss. If someone says for instance that their company is "belt-tightening" it usually means that there have been layoffs or a reduction in employee benefits or some other unpleasant cost-cutting measures.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Notch* is the word you are looking for to refer to holes in the belt. And I think there is no specific word for "wearing a belt", this is correct as per my knowledge. And I tightened my belt after losing some weight. It's similar to "tightening shoe lace".

Comment: I have absolutely no idea why the word "notch" didn't come to mind at the time. Thanks.

Comment: Please be aware that *as per my knowledge* isn’t “real English”. For details please see the answers to such questions as
[1](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/256),
[2](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/6473),
[3](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/20525).

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you say:

> Since I lost some weight I've been able to *cinch* my belt tighter.

Answer (score 0):

*Notch* refers to the holes in a belt. However, it is the *flopper* that sticks inside the *notch*. Hence, I believe the following sentence would be appropriate.

> I can now comfortably flopper two to three notches tighter (or down) when wearing a belt.

Comment: I would find "I can now wear my belt two or three notches tigher" clearer.

Comment: Even clearer, in my mind: *I can now tighten my belt two or three extra notches.*

Comment: I don't think this definition of *flopper* is widely understood or used. In fact, the three dictionaries I just checked (dictionary.com, merriam-webster, and wiktionary) do not contain anything resembling this definition. Are you sure you have the right word?

Comment: Now that just sounds dirty.

Comment: Flopper is seldom used. I blame my memory, but I read it in a book as the flopper referring to the stick. But am sure flopper is the word I read, don't remember the book though.